# Eclipse (Photon) Scrapbook VariableDeclarators Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQluWuxMT60&list=PLv6UtFrA7VEu4PtzJaGHHSeZBi6mdJtwv&index=9) youtube Eclipse+Java tutorial and having written following code which is taken from the video (around the 4:35 mark):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test1");
list.add("test2"); 
list;
```

getting the following error message when I try to highlight and evaluate the code within the Eclipse scrapbook:

> Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete
>   LocalVariableDeclaration

But the code runs fine on jshell. Also, in the scrapbook `import java.util.*` has been done. Thanks

Comment: What is the last line supposed to do?

Comment: @Turamarth: it is supposed to evaluate the statement `list`

Comment: Remove the semicolon on the final line after **list**.

Comment: @skomisa - thanks that works. I'm guessing that without the semi-colon it is an expression and hence evaluated but with the semi-colon its a statement and hence evaluation fails. is that correct?

Comment: @shanlodh Yes, except that based on the error message you got Eclipse seems to be treating `list;` as an invalid declaration rather than a statement. Also, note that the mere presence of the semicolon was not the direct cause of your problem; if you hadn't selected it when doing the **Inspect** everything would have been fine even though having a semicolon there is completely invalid.

Comment: @skomisa: thanks, you've helped answer my query so if you wish to post an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Thanks, but it is more appropriate for you to post the answer yourself.